# Error when using Jodatime object to store and query in parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, jodatime

Im trying to store and query on updatedAt and createdAt column in Parse.com class using a datetime object I created using jodatime. 
However, no matter what I am doing, I keep getting error.

Im doing following to create a datetime object that I want to store in Parse class.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTime trafficReportExpiry = dt.minusHours(1);

ParseObject trafficReport = new ParseObject("TrafficReport");
trafficReport.put("reportExpiry", trafficReportExpiry);

trafficReport.saveEventually();
```

When I run with following, I get a crash with following log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: info.androidhive.bdpocketbook, PID: 18022
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for value: class org.joda.time.DateTime
at com.parse.ParseObject.performPut(ParseObject.java:3023)
at com.parse.ParseObject.put(ParseObject.java:3010)
at info.androidhive.bdpocketbook.MainActivity.onConnected(MainActivity.java:255)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk.zzk(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzj.zzi(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzh.zzpx(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzh.onConnected(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzl.onConnected(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzc.onConnected(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzg.zzqL(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzc.zzqN(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Similar issue when I try to do using datatime object created using Joda at updatedAt column in Parse

My Parse.com query code:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTime trafficReportExpiry = dt.minusHours(1);

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("TrafficReport");

    query.setLimit(100);
    query.whereGreaterThan("updatedAt", trafficReportExpiry);

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> trafficObjects, ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"An error occurred while getting traffic data.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Parse traffic error", e.toString());
            }
            else {
                Log.e("trafficObjects", "Retrieved " + trafficObjects.size() + " traffic objects");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Traffic Data Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
                }
            }
    });
```

Parse query is failing with following log:

```
E/Parse traffic error: com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for ParseObject: class org.joda.time.DateTime
```

Im sure it have something to do with how datetime object is created. I tried to format it in many ways, but no luck.

Can anybody please point me to right direction.

Thanks a lot and any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse works with java Date objects..not with joda DateTime objects. They are not the same thing. So you must convert it to java Date before going anywhere near Parse.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion fixed my problem. I used following to convert Date dateNew = dateTime.toDate();